# Best method to update ubuntu 13.10 to path the HeartBleed bug

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, heartbleed

So we are running ubuntu 13.10 in production and they have `OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013`, which obviously needs to be patched.

1. What's the best way to do it without any downtime?
2. What will happen to the existing connections during the upgrade? Will    they be disconnected?
3. Will I need to reboot my server after the    upgrade?

Comment: "Install patches in the manner prescribed by your vendor." would be a good start. If you have other questions which are not specifically addressed in the marked duplicate please ask a new, more specific question...